# Ansible Display customize error message with "stat"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to validate the file path **if file exists or not**. I have written below task.

```
 - name: File Validation
   stat: path={{src_file_path}}{{filename}} get_md5=yes
   register: file
 - fail: msg="Whoops! File does not exist.!"
   when: file.stat.exists == False
```

"fail" module is throwing below error

```
TASK: [deploy-stack | fail msg="Whoops! File does not exist.!"] ***************
failed: [192.168.36.128] => {"failed": true}
msg: Whoops! File does not exist.!

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I am not getting why fail modules is by behaving as it suppose to.

Answer (score 2):

```
--- # Using stat - Check if a file exist on the remote system

- hosts: ec2
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no
  connection: ssh

  tasks:

    - name: check if the file is present or not
      stat: path=/opt/hello.yml
      register: p

    - debug: msg="Path exists and is a file"
      when: p.stat.isreg is defined and p.stat.isreg

    - debug: msg="do something here as the file is not present"
      when: p.stat.isreg == False
...

# Prints msg when it exists or skips it.
```

Comment: Thanks Chandan, I am trying to validate file on local host. If file exists,I will copy it on to the remote server and validate the checksum. 

In this case i am not able to handle exception if file path is changed. ansible is "skipping" the validation and file copying task.

Comment: you can just simply add another condition to do anything you want when its not present, so that it wont be skipped - updated the answer.